# CUDA Runtime Error: Which Cuda version is compatible to run NER task using BERT-NER

Tags: pytorch, named-entity-recognition, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have setup all the requirement packages installed on my VM and i found no nvidia GPU driver  installed, In the requirements doesn't have nvidia GPU driver installation instructions, I want to know which cuda version and it compatible nvidia driver which needs too resolve the below error.

Github link: [github](https://github.com/kamalkraj/BERT-NER)

**Error logs:**

```
  File "run_ner.py", line 594, in <module>
    main()
  File "run_ner.py", line 489, in main
    loss = model(input_ids, segment_ids, input_mask, label_ids,valid_ids,l_mask)
  File "/home/pt3_gcp/BERT-NER/ber_ner/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 547, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "run_ner.py", line 35, in forward
    valid_output = torch.zeros(batch_size,max_len,feat_dim,dtype=torch.float32,device='cuda')
  File "/home/pt3_gcp/BERT-NER/ber_ner/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 178, in _lazy_init
    _check_driver()
  File "/home/pt3_gcp/BERT-NER/ber_ner/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 99, in _check_driver
    http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx""")
AssertionError: 
**Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you
have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
**
```

After installing latest cuda version from the following link,
[cuda](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=debnetwork) I got the following error,

```
06/04/2020 07:38:40 - INFO - __main__ -   ***** Running training *****
06/04/2020 07:38:40 - INFO - __main__ -     Num examples = 14041
06/04/2020 07:38:40 - INFO - __main__ -     Batch size = 32
06/04/2020 07:38:40 - INFO - __main__ -     Num steps = 2190
Epoch:   0%|                                                                                 | 0/5 [00:00<?, ?it/sTHCudaCheck FAIL file=/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp line=50 error=38 : no CUDA-capable device is detectedt/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_ner.py", line 594, in <module>
    main()
  File "run_ner.py", line 489, in main
    loss = model(input_ids, segment_ids, input_mask, label_ids,valid_ids,l_mask)
  File "/home/pt3_gcp/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 547, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "run_ner.py", line 35, in forward
    valid_output = torch.zeros(batch_size,max_len,feat_dim,dtype=torch.float32,device='cuda')
  File "/home/pt3_gcp/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 179, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (38) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:50
```

Comment: Have you restarted the VM after installing the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: @MichaelJungo Yes

Comment: @MichaelJungo does this error affecting while installing latest cuda driver from sudo apt-get install cuda-driver-440 ? Or which driver version is preferable?

Comment: The newest version is usually preferred. For CUDA 10.2 the minimum required version is *440.33*, according to [CUDA Compatibility](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility). PyTorch cannot detect your GPU, which means either that the driver isn't correctly installed or that your GPU isn't supported (too old). Which GPU do you use? Could you post the output of `nvidia-smi` (that contains the relevant information and would fail if the driver wasn't installed correctly)?

Comment: $ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Comment: That means the driver isn't installed correctly. Try installing the latest driver with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450` and reboot afterwards, then check `nvidia-smi` again.

Comment: Yes tried, but getting the same, $ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215709/discussion-between-dwaynejohn-and-michael-jungo).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for some time ago. The following commands fixed for me!

It is a problem if you have multiple installation and likely you have now since you tried many things. Remove basically everything

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo apt autoremove --purge cuda-10-0 // you might have a different version, check it git cuda --version
```

also delete the existing files in your user base

```
rm -rf /usr/local/cuda* // anything related to cuda
rm -rf /usr/local/nvidia* // anything related to nvidia
```

Now, finally a fresh install

```
sudo apt-get update // update your packages

sudo apt search nvidia-driver  // to get the latest version of the driver. After finding out the latest version, install it with

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450 (or any other number, depending on the latest version)
```

After installing it, you must reboot!

```
sudo reboot
```

When you are back, `nvidia-smi` should work and also your gpus